# Highcharts Line Chart with Only x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, charts, highcharts

I've recently made the switch to Highcharts, for easy compatibility with IE8, and have been updating past projects because of the simplicity, but I have run into a minor hurdle.

In one project the last SVG element remaining is a single x-axis without any accompanying chart (see below). Is it possible to show only an x-axis in Highcharts without any accompanying series or y-axis? Or if not, is there a way to create this type of design as a DIV?

[image: SVG x-axis]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can display just xAxis. Don't add any of series, but set `xAxis.min` and `xAxis.max`. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/m4r1qttL/6/

Now just disable titles, legend etc.

Comment: This works quite well - https://jsfiddle.net/m4r1qttL/6/. But I can't seem to hide the 'No Data to Display' text in the center of the chart, is there an option to hide that? I included it in my custom build because I need it for other charts.

Comment: Figured it out -     noData: {
        style: {display: 'none'}
    }

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
yAxis: {
   ...  
   lineWidth: 0,
   minorGridLineWidth: 0,
   lineColor: 'transparent',
   ...          
   labels: {
       enabled: false
   },
   minorTickLength: 0,
   tickLength: 0
}
```

To the axis definition